# How do I build a full adder with a half adder?

Tags: c, logic

This is my Half Adder:

```
void HalfAdder(int a, int b, int * addrCarry, int * addrSum){
    *addrCarry = a && b;
    *addrSum = a != b;
}
```

How do I take that and make it a Full Adder?

Comment: You need two half-adders and an OR-gate. Look at the two sketches at the end: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volladdierer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how full adder implemented using the half adders:
[image]

So translation to C is straightforward:

```
void FullAdder(int a, int b, int cin, int * addrCarry, int * addrSum){
    int s1, c1, c2; // For intermediate results
    HalfAdder(a, b, &c1, &s1); // First adder stage
    HalfAdder(cin, s1, &c2, addrSum); // Second adder stage
    *addrCarry = c1 || c2;  // The OR stage
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: Recommend against using `cin` as a variable name as it may be confused for `C++ cin`.